# Efficiently converting and writing a vector to a handle

Tags: haskell, vector

I'm writing a program that performs a transformation on sample data in a file. I do this by reading the file, turning the content into a vector, performing the transformation on the vector and then writing the vector back to the file. I already (think) I have an efficient way of reading the file and turning its content into a vector but I'm still looking for an efficient way to write the resulting vector back to memory.

The samples in the file are 24 bit integers (3 bytes) and I transform them to floats by normalizing them.

I turn the file's content into a vector by reading all samples via `ByteString.hGet`. I can then simply use `Vector.generate` to convert every 3 bytes of the `ByteString` into a sample.

My problem is with writing the result back to a file. At least I think there is a problem. I'm currently converting the vector and writing it to a file as follows:

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import Data.ByteString as BS

putSamples :: Handle -> U.Vector Float -> IO ()
putSamples h vec = U.forM_ vec (BS.hPut h . BS.pack . unconvert 3 . Int)
```

As you can see, I first convert the `Float` back to an `Int` by de-normalizing it,turn the `Int` into 3 bytes via `unconvert 3`, `pack` the result into a `ByteString` of 3 bytes via `ByteString.pack` and then write the result to a handle via `ByteString.hPut`.

This seems terribly inefficient because I'm calling `hPut` for every single sample. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: I would probably wrap `U.Vector Float` in a `newtype` and create an instance for `Data.Serialize.Serialize`. I believe this will efficiently build a buffer that can then be written in one operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example shell creating a `Serialize` instance:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import qualified Data.Serialize as S

newtype MyVec = MyVec (U.Vector Float)

instance S.Serialize MyVec where
  put (MyVec vec) =
    U.forM_ vec $ \_ ->
      let word1 = 0; word2 = 0; word3 = 0
      in do
        S.putWord8 word1
        S.putWord8 word2
        S.putWord8 word3
  get = error "MyVec::S.Serialize: not implemented"

test = S.encode $ MyVec $ U.singleton 0
```

Comment: This seems to be faster than my original implementation. However, it seems to consume more memory. I need to run this on directories of files. I couldn't run this on a directory of 19 files since it swamps the memory. It does work using my previous implementation. Anyway, thanks for the input!

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden I would be interested to see your implementations, perhaps as a new question regarding the difference between the two? I'm not sure how the serialization method would affect memory consumption. Can each of your 19 files be processed individually or must some state be maintained across them? If the former, I would certainly make sure no references are held after a file has finished processing.